# Aren't these both plots of the residuals? If so, then what is the difference?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm analysing the `Boston` dataset from the [MASS package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf) in R. I begin by carrying out a linear regression with `medv` as the response and `ptratio` as the only predictor:

```
lm.Boston <- lm(formula = medv ~ ptratio, data = Boston.df)
```

I then want to plot the residuals. To this end, by following online tutorials, I have the following plots:

```
Boston.df$residuals <- lm.Boston$residuals
Boston.df$predicted <- predict(lm.Boston)

ggplot(Boston.df, aes(x = ptratio, y = medv)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "lightgrey") + # Plot regression slope
  geom_segment(aes(xend = ptratio, yend = predicted), alpha = 0.2) + # alpha to fade lines
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y = predicted), shape = 1) +
  theme_bw() # Add theme for cleaner look
```

[image]

```
plot(predict(lm.Boston), residuals(lm.Boston))
```

[image]

Looking at the points on each plot and the values of the axes, there clearly seems to be some significant difference between these two "residual" plots. However, I'm struggling to understand precisely what the difference is here (besides the obvious fact that one uses the generic `plot` function and the other uses `ggplot`). Aren't these both plots of the residuals? If so, then what is the difference? I'm assuming the confusion here stems from the complexity in the `ggplot` plot, since the `plot` plot is quite straightforwardly a plot of the residuals vs predicted values.

Comment: I wouldn't call the first plot a "residual plot" per se, although maybe some do? Note that at no point do you actually plot the residuals when making the first plot. That is a plot I've seen used in classes to explain the concept of residuals, though, as the added segments show the difference between each *observed* point and each *predicted* point (i.e., demonstrates the definition of a residual).

Comment: @aosmith Ahh, ok. Yes, the tutorial referred to it as a "plot of the residuals," but I noticed that it was fundamentally different to the plots presented in some of the other tutorials, so I was confused. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question -> no!

- The first plot with ggplot shows the data points from which you could
  "measure" or "inspect" the residuals!
- To plot the residuals with ggplot try this

```
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(lm.Boston)
```

- You should get 4 graphs the first one is relevant for you.
- This is similar to what you do with the base R plot -> Here you
  really plot the residuals.

Here is an example with the mtcars dataset:

```
lm.mtcars <- lm(formula = cyl ~ mpg, data =mtcars)

mtcars$residuals <- lm.mtcars$residuals
mtcars$predicted <- predict(lm.mtcars)

# plot1 your first ggplot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "lightgrey") + # Plot regression slope
  geom_segment(aes(xend = cyl, yend = predicted), alpha = 0.2) + # alpha to fade lines
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y = predicted), shape = 1) +
  theme_bw() # Add theme for cleaner look

# plot2 your R base plot
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
plot(mtcars$predicted, mtcars$residuals)

# plot3
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(lm.mtcars, which = 1, ncol = 1)
```

plot1:
[image]

plot2:
[image]

plot3: your ggfortify plot
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean "the data points from which you could "measure" or "inspect" the residuals"? You mean the data points from which you could "measure" or "inspect" the *predicted values* (as shown by the points on the regression line)?

Comment: When you perform simple linear regression (or any other type of regression analysis), you get a line of best fit. The data points usually don’t fall exactly on this regression equation line; they are scattered around. A residual is the vertical distance between a data point and the regression line. Each data point has one residual.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Ok, thanks for the clarification.